How to add an IDispatch COM object from C++ app in embedded Python that is created in the c++ code as a named object in Python and use it
I am able to use embedded Python in my MSVS Windows C++ app and it works well. I can create com objects and use them like this:
    import win32com.client as win32
    Dialogs = win32.Dispatch('DialogControls.Dialogs')
    Dialogs.Message(0, "Hello from C++ object")`

I have many objects that are created inside the C++ app and I want to access them and also their event handlers also in Python. Previously I used VBScript and I was able to do this with AddObjectEx but in Python I have no success. I tried something like this but it doesn't work. pComObject is NULL.
void PythonEng::PassComObjectToPython(const CString& ObjName, IDispatch* pMyComObject) {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("win32com.client");
    if (pModule) {
        PyObject* pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
        PyObject* pDispatch = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "Dispatch");
        if (pDispatch && PyCallable_Check(pDispatch)) {
            PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyLong_FromVoidPtr(pMyComObject));
            PyObject* pComObject = PyObject_CallObject(pDispatch, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pComObject) {
                PyObject* pGlobals = PyDict_New();
                CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString(ObjName);
                std::string strObjName(pszConvertedAnsiString);
                PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, strObjName.c_str(), pComObject);
                Py_DECREF(pComObject);
                // Now you can execute Python code that uses my_com_object
                PyRun_String("MyGen.Idle(10)", Py_file_input, pGlobals, pGlobals);
                Py_DECREF(pGlobals);
            }
        }
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    Py_Finalize();
}

I tried to add my com object with the above code and use it from embedded Python.

That your COM object is implemented in C++ shouldn't matter. You should be able to directly use it from python.  I would not recommmend bridging more than 1 technology, python, C++ and COM all have their own different life cycle rules so you're actually not making things simpler.

You are right but the problem is that I need to replace VBScript used to automate and customize tasks in an existing C++ app. Some COM objects are created in the context of the main app and are added as named IDispatch objects in the script to allow to call their methods and access properties.

Do you need very detailed access to your com objects? If my approach would be to define an API from your C++ app to python (using extern "C") that way you have ONE clear interface between scripting and your C++ internal design. (COM objects have a tendency to expose a lof of methods and I can't imagine you need all of them).  Really sounds to me like you have to refactor an organically grown something into something with at least a little bit of desing. Bonus points : you can implement a mock for your extern "C" interface and do some scripting unit testing.

Thank you for your answer! I don't need very detailed access but the idea was to port the existing VBScripts to Python and it is a lot of work. If it is needed also to refactor the C++ part it becomes even worse. I am wandering if it is possible to do this at all like the VBScript AddObjectEx . VBScript is ok but MS will stop the support and I need an alternative.

No problem, also my view comes from 40 years of experience of developing and maintaining very large code bases (so I might be biased to taking extra pain now to avoid pain later). If the code is intended to be used in a production environment, I would say a bit of refactoring (and update of quality) is always worth the effort. I am not saying you need to refactor the C++ code, but to add an adapter in front of it (e.g. a small "C" layer, that can make the calls to C++ and COM code for you). Once you have that making calls from any scripting language should be more easy.

I agree but I faced additional problems with visual components running in the C++ and Python environment. Even simple code causes unstable behavior and crashes. I prefer a custom automation solution that can be customized where needed with small Python scripts. I did very successful and stable pure Python AI project and I read that it can be interfaced to C++ but no good source of information and samples. Many APIs are obsolete and new. I will abandon this solution and will use different approach. Thank you for your help!

You're welcome, even though I think wasn't much help ;)

Here are some ideas for you:
#define NOMINMAX
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <cassert>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <MsXml6.h>
#include <string>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ALL your legacy + COM code

class legacy_cpp_com_code
{
public:
    legacy_cpp_com_code()
    {
        // make sure ::CoInitializeEx has been called etc. 
        auto hr = m_xmlDocument.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument60, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
    }

    std::wstring GetName()
    {
        ATL::CComBSTR str;
        m_xmlDocument->get_baseName(&str);
        return { static_cast<LPWSTR>(str) };
    }

    void some_method()
    {
    }

private:
    ATL::CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> m_xmlDocument;
};

// Or you can use these kind of COM factory methods, to later hide the COM objects in "C" API calls.

ATL::CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> GetXmlDocument()
{
    // initialization from lamda into a static com pointer (this will be released when the library unloads)
    static ATL::CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> xmlDocument = []
    {  
        ATL::CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> localXmlDocument;
        auto hr = localXmlDocument.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument60, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
        return localXmlDocument;
    }();

    return xmlDocument;
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Your "new" scripting API

legacy_cpp_com_code instance;


extern "C"
{
    const wchar_t* GetName(void)
    {
        return instance.GetName().c_str();

        // or
        // GetXmlDocument().GetName().c_str();
    }

    void some_method(void)
    {
        instance.some_method();
    }
}

